# Is it possible to change the content of place card in google map

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am displaying google map using iframe using longitude and latitude.
It displays the map with a place card which contains the longitude and latitude.
Is there a way to get the address instead of longitude and latitude in the place card?

```
<iframe id="mapframe" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=latitude,longitude&key=Google map API key" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)

You can if you use the Address as the query, I investigated and here are the result image below:

Embedded API using coordinates as query

[image]

Embedded API using Address as query
[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use: (1 infinite loop example)

```
?q=1+infinite+loop+cupertino+ca+95014
```

It's the best to provide everything you know, like street, zip and town. Then this should work fine